# How can I grab a date out of a string and format it?

Tags: php, string, date, datetime, preg-match

I have PDF-files on my server saved like:

```
945_20140610_Eve_Ikras.pdf
```

I want to break out the year, month and day separately.

```
$file = "945_20140610_Eve_Ikras.pdf";

if(preg_match("/\d{4}\-d{2}\-d{2}/", $file, $match))
    print_r($match);
```

Output:

```
Array (
  [0] => 20140610
)
```

But I want to format the date like this:

```
2014-06-10
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it actually match? Your regex matches something like `2014-dd-dd`. `\d{4}\d{2}\d{2}` is probably what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is just to create a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object (Since you have a special format here you have to use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to create your object) and then you can format your date as you want it with [`format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), e.g.

```
$file = "945_20140610_Eve_Ikras.pdf";

if(preg_match("/\d{4}\d{2}\d{2}/", $file, $match)) {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Ymd", $match[0]);
    echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
}
```

output:

```
2014-06-10
```